# Value keeps displaying twice when looping through rows in a table

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli, row

I'm trying to loop through a table in my database, row by row, using a for loop.

However, the value is displayed twice instead of once. E.g. If the user's first name is 'frank', it displays 'frank' twice,  like 'frank frank.' If the user's surname is 'ocean', it displays it as 'ocean ocean'. I only want the name to display once!

```
$results = mysqli_query ($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++ ) {
    echo "<p>" . $row["user_f_name"] . "</p>"; 
    echo "<p>" . $row["user_surname"] . "</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` does not return all rows from the query. It only fetches one at a time. You need to call `mysqli_fetch_array()` in a loop; there are numerous examples on this site as to how that is done. There's a complete example on the PHP tag wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info  under "Why does mysqli_fetch_array() return only one row"

Comment: I understand that it only returns the rows one at a time, but why is it displaying twice though? I want it to only display once, as you mentioned.

Comment: Apparently there are two rows in `users`. `$row` contains the first row after you do the fetch, but `$total_rows` is `2`, so when you do the `for` loop, you see the one row you fetched twice.

Comment: @Don't Panic Thank you! That makes sense. How do I fix this problem though?

Comment: Just fetch your rows in a while loop as shown in the answer to the linked duplicate.